# Problem in understanding local compactness of an Appert space.

Tags: general-topology

I wonder how an Appert space is not locally compact. For local compactness, any point other than 1 is easy to understand but I have problem with the point 1. I have already proved that it is compact.  Please help me.

Comment: I do not know this space.  What is its description?

Comment: $X=\mathbb Z^+$  and $\tau = \{A \subseteq X : 1 \notin A \} \cup \{A \subseteq X : \frac \ {# \{a \in A : a \leq n \}} {n} $

Comment: Your error appears to be in the \frac command.

Comment: @Randall [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appert_topology)

Comment: The whole space is not compact. Have you shown this?

Comment: See $Appert$ $ Topology$ in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show that in any set $A\subset \omega$ of density $1$ there is a subset $A'\subset A$ of density $1$ such that $A\setminus A'$ is infinite. This implies non local compactness at $1$.